# Functional dependencies and candidate key example

Tags: database-design, normalization

Hi there I'm still learning for my examination and I got this exercise:

A table is given:

```
F-Name,           F-Nation,    Team-Name,   Team-Nation 
-------------------------------------------------------
Lance Armstrong,     USA,   Discovery Channel,   USA 
Jose Luis Rubiera,   ESP,   Discovery Channel,   USA 
Jan Ullrich,         GER,   Team Telekom,        GER 
Andreas Klöden,      GER,   Team Telekom,        GER 
Davide Rebellin,     IT,    Team Gerolsteiner,   GER
```

---

a) Which are the candidate keys?

b) Which non-trivial functional dependencies existing?

c) Is the table in 2NF (second normal form)? If not modify the table to be in 2NF.

d) Is the table in 3NF (third normal form)? If not modify the table to be in 3NF.

---

a) I would say that the candidate keys are `(F-Name, Team-Name)` or `(F-Name, Team-Nation)`

b) The dependencies are:

```
Team-Name -> Team-Nation
F-Name -> F-Nation
```

c) no it is not in 2NF because `Team-Nation` is not dependant from the `F-Name` which is part of the key candidate.

Table after normalization to 2NF:

Table driver

```
F-Name, F-Nation, Team-Name
```

Table teams

```
Team-Name, Team-Nation
```

d) I couldn't find any transitive relations so I guess the solution of c) would be in 3NF also am I right?

Comment: Based on the data, `F-Name` seems to be a candidate key by itself. And since the candidate keys can be deduced by dependies, you have missed some dependencies.

Comment: b) If the dependencies were only those two, the only candidate key would be `(F-Name, Team-Name)`. How did you come with the second one?

Answer (score -2):

Ok so I can say on a) there are two solutions. If `F-Name` is Unique the candidate key is `F-Name` otherwise `F-Name, Team-Name`

b) The dependencies are:

```
F-Name -> F-Nation, Team-Name
Team-Name -> Team-Nation
```

and my solutions on c) and d) are right?

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.